# azure analyis service Processing using .NET Activity in Azure data factory how we get ServicePrincipalAuth information from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-analysis-services

### following Azure reference site for analysis service processing costume .NET activity

`https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/AzureAnalysisServicesProcessSample`

in this example we have  Pipeline to Process Cube

```
`       "TabularDatabaseName": "<DATABASE_NAME>",
        "AzureADAuthority": "https://login.windows.net/<TENANT_ID>",
        "AzureADResource": "https://<LOCATION>.asazure.windows.net",
        "AzureADClientId": "<CLIENT_ID>",
        "AzureADClientSecret": "<CLIENT_SECRET>"`
```

first we need to know how we get AzureADResource and AzureADAuthority information.

also this pipeline working fine when we pass hard-coded password instead of {0)

so we  didn't understand where is problem. is ServicePrincipalAuth we provided here is correct or it is mandatory to provide password

Regards,
Manish

Comment: here is connection string -"AzureASConnectionString": "Data Source=asazure://<LOCATION>.asazure.windows.net/<NAME>;User ID=;Password={0};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate",

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this article from MSDN which mentions how to create an application in the AD and create AD service principal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-create-data-factories-programmatically

Step 7 would return the AD service principal.

Also, to be able to run a pipeline you would require a client when creating a connection with ADF, which would require client Id, client Key, subscription Id and tenant Id.

**This is how I created my client to ADF.**

```
private void CreateADFClient()
    {
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}");
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: this.client_id, clientSecret: this.client_key);
        Task<AuthenticationResult> result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        string token = result.Result.AccessToken;

        TokenCloudCredentials credentials = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscription_id, token);
        this.inner_client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials);
    }
```

The application name that you provided while performing the steps from MSDN, will return the name of the application, take note of the application name & find it on the Azure portal by Azure Active Directory --> App Registrations --> . Corresponding to it would be your application id which is the **client Id** here.

To create the **client key**, click on the application name and go to 'Keys' section and add a key description and validation and save. Upon saving the value would be shown, this is your client key. Please take note of it, this would be visible the next time you come to this page, but of course, you can create another.

The **tenant id** can be downloaded by clicking on Help --> show diagnostics. A file will be downloaded where you can search your tenant Id from.

Hope this solves your questions around it!

Comment: i got this url -https://feedback.azure.com/forums/556165-azure-analysis-services/suggestions/19373743-add-support-for-service-principle-authentication

Comment: as per above URL this feature will not work please confirm

Comment: I am sorry, could you brief your problem here. I cannot understand your question.